# How do I concatenate two Json Objects using Json.Net (newtonsoft)

Tags: c#, json.net

I have JSON objects that I want to concatenate into one JSON object.

How do I do that using NewtonSoft's JSON package?

Comment: Seems the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14121010/merge-two-json-net-jtokens

Comment: use the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21160337/how-can-i-merge-two-jobject/21236171#21236171

Comment: @PeterRitchie Related, but not a duplicate. The other question is specifically about merging arrays by concatenating them. I updated the title on that question to make this clear (before this was only mentioned in the question text).

Answer (score 6):

Use `JContainer.Merge()`.

> The logic for combining JSON objects together is fairly simple: name/values are copied across, skipping nulls if the existing property already has a value.

[Json.NET 6.0 Release 4](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2014/08/04/json-net-6-0-release-4-json-merge-dependency-injection)

Example:

```
var jObject1 = // Your first json object as JObject
var jObject2 = // Your second json object as JObject 

jObject1.Merge(jObject2);

// jObject1 contains now the merged properties from jObject2.
```

Note that for properties that exist in both objects, the `jObject2` ones take precedence (i.e. overwrite the properties in `jObject1`).

Comment: What if you want to copy the nulls across too