# How do I check existence of an Object in a JObject and add a new Object if not present or add this to the existing Object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, object, json.net

I'm trying to find a solution to check the existence of Object "key6" in the JSON shown below:

```
{
   "key1": "www.microsoft0nline.nl/test.php",
   "key2": "2019-06-05 11:21:09",
   "key3": "otherValue1",
   "key4": "433",
   "key5": [
     "35",
     "37",
     "43"
   ],
   "key6": {
       "nameOther: "object123456",
       "descriptionOther": "A object type123456",
       "sizeOther": 120123456
   }
}
```

If the key in the JSON does not exist, I want to add a new Object to my JObject with the name of the Object and a key-value pair within, like this:

```
//Base JObject
JObject obj = new JObject();

//create JObject to add into my base JObject
JObject otherObj = new JObject();
otherObj.Add(new JProperty(keyOfObject, property.Value));

//check if property does not already exists
foreach (JProperty property1 in obj.Properties().ToList()) //check if object already exists
{
    if (objectName.Equals(property1.Name)) //Exists
    {                                              
          property1.Add(otherObj);
    }
    else
    {
         obj.Add(new JProperty(objectName, otherObj));
    }
}
```

If the key does exist, it will just need to add a key-value pair into the existing object.

Does anyone have suggestions about how to achieve this? The code above shows the following error:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

I've written some code that partly works:

```
//check if property does not already exists
if (objectExists == false && property.Name.Equals(item.KeyOther))
{
    obj.Add(new JProperty(objectName, otherObj));
    objectExists = true;
} else if (objectExists == true && property.Name.Equals(item.KeyOther))
{
    foreach (JProperty property1 in obj.Properties().ToList()) //check if object already exists
    {
        if (property1.Name.Equals(objectName))
        {                                                         
             property1.Add(otherObj);
        }
    }
}
```

The "if-condition" in the code above works fine, when there is not a object with the name "key6" the object and the key-value pair within this object are added, also the boolean "objectExists" is set to true. When there is another key-value pair within the same object(key) detected I need to add this to the already existing "key6" object instead of creating a new object, this is what I'm trying to do in the "else-condition". However this does not work, does anyone have suggestions how to add a key-value pair to an existing Jproperty?

The property after finishing the "if-condition" looks as this:

[image]

Within the "key6" I want to add another key-value pair besides key "nameOther" with its value "www.microsoft0nline.nl/test.php".

Comment: Use [`JToken.Merge`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/MergeJson.htm)?  See e.g. [Merge two JTokens into one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37756656) or [How can I merge two JObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25621089).

Comment: My obj is my base object with different key-value pairs, arrays and objects within. I added a regular object into this base object but i dont know how to add more key-value pairs into this object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using "ContainsKey" method to find the existence of particular key object. Hope example below could help you,

```
    //Base JObject
    JObject obj = new JObject();
    obj["key1"] = "www.microsoft0nline.nl/test.php";
    obj["key2"]= "2019-06-05 11:21:09";
    obj["key3"] = "otherValue1";
    //create JObject to add into my base JObject
    JObject otherObj = new JObject();
    string objectName = "key2";
    otherObj.Add(new JProperty(objectName, "valuehelloworld"));
    if(obj.ContainsKey(objectName))
    {
        objectExists = true;
    }
    else{
    obj.Add(new JProperty(objectName, otherObj));
    }
```